# counting active visitors using global.asa only for specific page

Tags: asp-classic

using a code like this will count the active visitors on my website.

**global.asa**

```
Sub Application_OnStart
    Application("ActiveUsers") = 0
End Sub

Sub Session_OnStart
    Session.Timeout = 20
    Session("Start") = Now
    Application.Lock
    Application("ActiveUsers") = Application("ActiveUsers") + 1
    Application.UnLock
End Sub

Sub Session_OnEnd
    Application.Lock
   Application("ActiveUsers") = Application("ActiveUsers") - 1
    Application.UnLock
End Sub
```

What I need is only for a specific page - it is for a waiting list for a chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `global.asa` in such case.

You will have to write code in that specific page.

Increasing the visitors count is trivial: just have this code in the page:

```
Application.Lock
Application("ChatUsers") = Application("ChatUsers") + 1
Application.UnLock
```

The tricky part is to **decrease** the count when someone leaves the page. For this you have to use client side script and AJAX: client side script triggered in the page `unload` event will send request to the server telling it that someone left the page.

Most common and simple way is by using jQuery - so such code in the `.asp` should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind("unload", function() {
        $.ajax({ url: "<%=Request.ServerVariables("Script_Name")%>", type: "POST", data: "visitor_has_left=true",  async: false });
    });
</script>
```

This will send the AJAX request, now to handle it have such ASP code:

```
<%
If Request.Form("visitor_has_left")="true" Then
    If Application("ChatUsers")>0 Then
        Application.Lock
        Application("ChatUsers") = Application("ChatUsers") - 1
        Application.UnLock
    End If
    Response.End()
Else  
    Application.Lock
    Application("ChatUsers") = Application("ChatUsers") + 1
    Application.UnLock
End If
%>
```

(It already combines the code to increase the count as well)

Just tested it now and it works, hope the concept is clear as well.

Note, I set `async` to `false` because of Chrome: it's smart enough to cancel the request if the document changing location right after sending the request, so waiting for response force even Chrome to send the desired request.

Comment: Thanks @Rory let's hope it help the OP as well. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard the aswer is great, i will try it soon... thanks - the answer is clear and great!

Comment: Cheers @Y.G.J hope you won't face any problems.. by the way may I ask what your avatar means? Couldn't figure this out.. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard... are you for real? it is me (stamp version of my photo in photoshop) and israel flag

Comment: @Y.G.J lol I know the flag from experience, but at first glance it looked like it was burned or something then I realized it's drawing of a person but still wasn't sure what's the catch. Is this your own doing?